# Difference between vip and vap

Tags: vim

In vim, I frequently use <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to select a paragraph and format to the correct width. However, I have also seen <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> suggested. What is the difference? They both seem to do the exact same thing.

Comment: No strong reason to use `v` in this case. Visual mode often gets used unnecessarily. You could have just done `gqap`.

Comment: Depending on where you are in the paragraph, you could also use `gq}`.

Comment: After a little trial and error, I've decided to go with `gqip` because it is the least cumbersome of the combinations, with one finger for each key. I can type the whole combination in a very small fraction of a second. Long live `vim`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authoritative explanations can be found with vim's help documentation.
Try `:help v_a` or `:help v_i` (both are in the same location). The difference is that `v_a` selects the paragraph, including the white space, whereas `v_i` selects only the paragraph itself.

With respect to the command `gq` (see `:help gq`), the result of `v_a` and `v_i` is identical, since the white space is not formatted by the `gq` command.